# React Hooks with Redux persisting the App state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I just started learning react hooks and react-redux hooks and as far I understood everything. But one thing is keep drilling my brain, so I would like to ask more experienced developers here.

If I have more robust app, where I intend to have Redux taking care of whole state and wanna use React hooks fro side effects, do I really need React Hooks?

I have separate functional layer (containers => where all the decisions are being made with redux) and displaying layer (components => where components are dumb and obtain just data they are suppose to render)

Whats bugging me is I make a API call in initial page loading and I would like to use useEffect hook, but im not conviced I should do that when I can useSelector from redux and useDispatch.

here is the code I would like to update into hook style:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    cities: state.weather.cities,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  const fetchForUpdate = (cities) => {
    return cities.map((city) => {
      return dispatch({ type: FETCH_START, payload: city.name })
    })
  }

  return {
    fetchForUpdate: fetchForUpdate,
  }
}

const WeatherListContainer = (props) => {
  const { cities } = props
  const cityData = cities.map((oneCity) => {
    return (
      <WeatherItemContainer
        name={oneCity.name}
        data={oneCity.data}
        key={oneCity.name}
      />
    )
  })

  return <WeatherList item={cityData} />
}

const enhance: Function = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.props.cities, 'this.props.cities')
      this.props.fetchForUpdate(this.props.cities)
    },
  }),
)

export default enhance(WeatherListContainer)
```

how can I fetch with redux hooks or react hooks? Or can I combine it? like use useEffect and then save it from local store to global store? Isnt it a bit ineffective?

Answer (score 1):

Redux requires a middleware such as redux-thunk to dispatch asynchronous actions (an API call). If you plan on calling an API multiple times throughout your app, it makes sense to use redux-thunk and dispatch an asynchronous action, though this dispatch might still need to occur within useEffect/componentDidMount. If you only plan on a single API call, or if a specific side effect is unique to one component, there is no need to implement the middleware. For a single API call, you can send your request within useEffect/componentDidMount and then dispatch the result with a synchronous action to the redux store, without having to ever store it in component state.

https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Comment: Thanks Pavlos. The API is going to be called multiple times, based on user's option, so I guess Thunk is the best choice

Comment: So with thunk, lets the the user makes their selection and then submits via a click. The onClick handler should then dispatch an asynchronous action that takes in their selection as an argument. Within the asynchronous action, other synchronous actions can be dispatched after the API returns its result. This just means the result doesn't need to return back to the component and can be dispatched directly into the store.

Comment: okay, if I need to avoid useState hook in react component, how can I update the react component's state, when the state should be only in redux? Thats what I am missing

Comment: You don't need to entirely ignore useState hook; if a component needs to keep track of its visibility (show/hide toggle), that's something that shouldn't be done through redux. For data shared between multiple components, you would use the useSelector hook to monitor the redux store within the component, and when redux updates, so do the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some confusions. React hooks are used for sideEffects where redux hooks are for using the store more efficientl.    Lets consider a scenario like bellow.

You are fetching a todo list from API and wanna use it all over the app. You have multiple components and you are gonna need the todo list in every component. In that case, you will call the api either using a middleware like `redux-thunk` or by other means like caling it in a `useEffect`( which is not a good practice) and save it to redux store using redux hooks. And whenever you redux store is updated, you will need to show the data in components. How will we do that? we will use react hooks to apply the sideEffects.

Here we will get the data from redux store using redux hooks. Than in a reactHooks like `useEffect` we will update a state of the component using `useState`.  So here you can see, both `reactHooks` and `reduxHooks` are completely different in terms of functionality. one is storing and serving data which is `reduxHooks` and another one is showing the data when ever its added or updated which is `reactHooks`.

Hope you will find it understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds like too many hooks :-D. Well since I use Redux for perserving the whole App state, I dont need to use useState, right? Or useState is just updating the component state to be it in accordance with Global app state?

Comment: suppose you added data in your redux and showed it your component first time. Then you updated the data in store from api again.  In that case,  just because you updated the redux store, it will not update your component. You will need to tell your component that the store is updated so re render. With redux hooks, you can not communicate with your component.  You have to do it using reacthooks

Comment: okay, I understand. But question is which hook from react should I use to update the component from the rdedux store, useEffect hook?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `useEffect` with a dependency array of the store value. in that case, when ever the store is updated, the useEffect will be triggere.